# Erro em gerar Gráfico de pizza "pie" em highchart ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Estou tendo problemas para gerar um gráfico de pizza no estilo de `Highcharts`. Eu tenho o seguinte código para gerar a série:

```
if (vlrTot1 >= 0) 
        { 
            Dictionary<string, object> aSeries = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
            aSeries["data"] = new List<object[]>(); 
            aSeries["name"] = "TIR <= " + vlrLimInf.ToString();

            object[] values = new object[2]; 
            decimal vlr1 = Math.Round(((vlrTot1 / (vlrTot1 + vlrTot2 + vlrTot3)) * 100),  1 ); 
            values[0] = "TIR <= " + vlrLimInf.ToString(); 
            values[1] = vlr1; 
            ((List<object[]>)aSeries["data"]).Add(values); 
            dataResult.Add(aSeries);

        } 
        if (vlrTot2 >= 0) 
        { 
            Dictionary<string, object> aSeries = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
            aSeries["data"] = new List<object[]>(); 
            aSeries["name"] = vlrLimInf.ToString() + " > TIR <= " + vlrLimSup.ToString();

            object[] values = new object[ 2 ]; 
            decimal vlr2 = Math.Round(((vlrTot2 / (vlrTot1 + vlrTot2 + vlrTot3)) * 100),  1); 
            values[0] = vlrLimInf.ToString() + " > TIR <= " + vlrLimSup.ToString(); 
            values[1] = vlr2; 
            ((List<object[]>)aSeries["data"]).Add(values); 
            dataResult.Add(aSeries);

        } 
        if (vlrTot3 >= 0) 
        { 
            Dictionary<string, object> aSeries = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
            aSeries["data"] = new List<object[]>(); 
            aSeries["name"] = "TIR > " + vlrLimSup.ToString();

            object[] values = new object[2]; 
            decimal vlr3 = Math.Round(((vlrTot3 / (vlrTot1 + vlrTot2 + vlrTot3)) * 100),  1); 
            values[0] = "TIR > " + vlrLimSup.ToString(); 
            values[1] = vlr3; 
            ((List<object[]>)aSeries["data"]).Add(values); 
            dataResult.Add(aSeries);
        }
```

Que está gerando este gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As duas séries estão aparecendo com 100%.

Mas o gráfico correto teria que ser este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo está a saída para gerar o gráfico com json:

```
var data = ServiceGraf.GetValuesByGrafPie(....PARAMETERS....);

                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Eu não sei onde está errado. Abaixo encontra-se o valor do Json de saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
function (data) {
                 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container',
                            ignoreHiddenSeries: false,
                            type: graf,
                            plotBackgroundColor: null,
                            plotBorderWidth: null,
                            plotShadow: false

                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Gráfico do Levantamento de ' + levant
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            pie: {
                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                showInLegend: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: data
                    });
                   }
```

Comment: O Highcharts, a priori, aceita um array de object (`object[]`). O que você está passando é uma lista de arrays de object, o que pode fazer o script se perder.

Comment: Para o gráfico de linha, eu fiz praticamente a mesma coisa, e funcionou muito bem para ter varias séries, mas com este não sei o que esta ocorrendo.

Comment: A diferença é que o grafico de linha aceita series enquanto o grafico de pizza não.

Comment: Descobri o que estava dando de errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colocando desta forma resolve o problema.

```
       var dataResult = new List<List<Object>>();
        dataResult.Add(new List<object>(new object[] { leg1.ToString(), vlr1 }));
        dataResult.Add(new List<object>(new object[] { leg2.ToString(), vlr2 }));
        dataResult.Add(new List<object>(new object[] { leg3.ToString(), vlr3 }));
```